# Redshift COPY command - Backend what happens?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to COPY a csv large file (~30Gb) from S3 to Redshift using the Redshift COPY command. What happens in the Redshift backend when this COPY command is run?

- Is the upload single threaded or multi-threaded?
- Does the file get split into smaller size before it then uploads to
  Redshift?
- Is there any documentation of how this command works?

Answer (score 1):

From [Loading data from Amazon S3 - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Loading-data-from-S3.html):

> The COPY command leverages the Amazon Redshift massively parallel processing (MPP) architecture to **read and load data in parallel from a file or multiple files in an Amazon S3 bucket**. You can take maximum advantage of parallel processing by splitting your data into multiple files, in cases where the files are compressed. You can also take maximum advantage of parallel processing by setting distribution keys on your tables.

The load process is distributed across nodes. However, if the incoming data is only in a single file, I suspect that it will be single-threaded. It is more efficient to load data from multiple files, since they can be loaded in parallel.